# How to use PipeViewer(pv) on Mac OS with dd

Tags: macos, ubuntu, dd

I'm trying to copy a .img of Ubuntu 14.04.1 to my bootable usb using the command `sudo dd if=~/Documents/targetUbuntu.img of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m` but it's taking long and I can't see the progress. So i'm trying to use pv using this command `sudo dd if=~/Documents/targetUbuntu.img | pv | dd of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m` but im getting this error: `dd: /dev/rdisk1: Permission denied`. If I do do ctrl-C in the first scenario where its taking too long it tells me that it copied over X amount of bytes in X secs and that's it. When I try to boot the usb, it says "isolinux.iso is missing or corrupt". So I want to make sure that file is copying over properly and I want to do that by using pv to check the progress, but I keep getting that error. Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect its because the sudo is only being used for the first command in your pipe, where you are using dd to read the image file.
[See this answer over on the unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106663/how-do-you-process-an-entire-command-as-sudo-that-involves-redirecting-or-piping)

Or you can try instead something like:

  `sudo "pv -tpreb myubuntu.img | dd of=/dev/sdc`

[per post by Greg Kroah-Hartman on g+](https://plus.google.com/111049168280159033135/posts/Y1kUiH4vvb9)

Answer (score 5):

Add sudo to the second "dd" command instead.

```
dd if=~/Documents/targetUbuntu.img | pv | sudo dd of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m
```

You'll also want to provide "size" to pv command (replace 123456 with file size.)

```
dd if=~/Documents/targetUbuntu.img | pv -s 123456 | sudo dd of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m
```